# Find the smallest ring generated by all singleton subsets of an uncountable set.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable set and let $E$ be the collection of all singleton subsets of $X$.

Find the smallest ring generated by $E$.

**Attempt**:
Let  $R$ be the ring generated by $E$.

Let $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ be any elements in $X$. Let $R_{1}$ be the smallest ring containing $A_{1} \setminus A_{2}$, $A_{2} \setminus A_{1}$, and $A_{1} \cap A_{2}$.

So $R_{1} = \{ \emptyset, A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{1} \cap A_{2}, A_{1} \cup A_{2} \} $.

Let $R_{2}$ be the smallest ring containing $R_{1}$ and next element in $X \setminus A_{1} \setminus A_{2}$

Add all the elements add the elements $(A_{1} \cap A_{2}) \cap A_{3}$ and $(A_{1} \cup A_{2}) \cup A_{3}$ to $R_{2}$

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. First, I suppose you mean *ring of sets* instead of *ring*, but the term [ring of set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) is itself ambiguous. Given the tag, I suppose you want to use the sense of measure theory: a ring of sets is a nonempty family closed under finite unions and set-theoretic differences.

Answer (score 0):

The set of finite subsets of $X$ is the smallest ring of sets (in the sense of measure theory) containing the singletons. Indeed every finite set is a finite union of singletons. Moreover the difference of two finite sets is also a finite set. The fact that $X$ is uncountable is irrelevant.